# android calculate speed on the background

Tags: android, geolocation, location

I am working on a simple app that calculate the current speed of the phone using onLocationChanged method, and it working fine but the problem is if I pressed the home button and the app was running on the background the calculating of the speed will stop until I open the app again, and I want to make the app calculate the current speed whenever the app is on Foreground or background until the user close it.

I tried using OnLifecycleEvent but I don't know how to call onLocationChanged method from it

here is the code to calculate the current speed
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

```
    if (location == null) {

        txt.setText("0.0");
    } else {
        CurrentSpeed = location.getSpeed() * 3.6f;
   
    }
 }
```

here is the code that check if the app is on Foreground or background:

```
    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_STOP)
private void onAppBackgrounded() {
    Log.d("MyApp", "App in background");
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "App in background", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}

@OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_START)
private void onAppForegrounded() {
    Log.d("MyApp", "App in foreground");
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "pp in foreground", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Use service to achieve the required task.

Comment: You would have to write a background service for that so it can run even when your app is in the background or closed.
The system kills processes when it needs to free up RAM; the likelihood of the system killing a given process depends on the state of the process at the time